# Windows : Compress the drive/file/folder to save disk space

Tags: windows, hard-drive, compression

This option is available for both my primary as well as external hard disk.

I was wondering about the pros and cons of this feature.
I found some at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/compress-this-drive-to-save-disk-space-does-anyone/cacb889a-66c4-4a51-b742-f94f9fe5c6af
Are these two points all (on the above link) or are there other pros and cons as well?

Somewhere it was also written that this feature does not compress pictures and video files but it seems to work on those files as well.
So, i was wondering if this compression is lossy or lossless?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using it for a few years and no issues so far (maybe I've just been lucky though). The major purpose of mine is to save disk spaces of rarely-used files which are uncompressed by default. e.g. plain texts, bitmaps, rarely-used applications. However, I don't enable that on important files unless auto-backup is configured. It is really useful on SSD drives which are still expensive but I don't usually enable them on HDDs. Sometimes, at work, it helps to overcome network drive's slow performances as well as to delay new HDD purchases. It's true that HDDs are cheap to buy, but the man price to maintain them is not cheap.

The well known downside (except of fragility) is performance. For example, if you enable it on your Windows folder or Temp folder, the whole system performance will get slower. This is the reason I don't enable them on frequently-used files.

On media files, it is true that the attributes can be set on them, but actually they aren't compressed. When you see their properties on Windows Explorer, the actual file sizes are same as the original ones, which means Windows doesn't touch them if compressed one is bigger than the original. I don't worry about that at all. In addition, I believe that all this compression is lossless.